# Membership operator in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python

I have been trying to create a login system using a nested dictionary. The first dictionary contains the key as user_type and value as another dictionary of the key as user_name and value as a password.
I wanted to check whether a username exists in a dictionary that is nested. I have been facing some errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 130, in <module>
    if uname in user.values().keys():
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

My code is

```
user = {
  "admin" : {"alex" : "1234", "phil" : "3453", "peter" : "23423", "lucas" : "12133"},
  "student" : {"tanishk" : "23423", "sanskar" : "7445", "shashwat" : "5573", "ayush" : "96456"}
}

uname = input("Enter your username : ").lower()

if uname in user.values().keys():
  print("Hello")
```

Comment: `if any(uname in mp for mp in user.values())`

Comment: Instead of nested dictionaries for admins and students, use a dictionary whose keys are usernames, and values are dictionaries like `{'id': "1234", "admin": True}`

Answer (score 0):

Mechanic Pig's comment gives the answer.

```
if any(uname in mp for mp in user.values())
```

Here is the explanation:

`user.values()` returns a sequence of values of all items in the outer dictionary.  Something like:

```
[
  {"alex": "1234", "phil": "3453", "peter": "23423", "lucas": "12133"},
  {"tanishk": "23423", "sanskar": "7445", "shashwat": "5573", "ayush": "96456"},
]
```

It is just not a list, but a `'dict_values' object`, but it works similarly like a list.  This object has no method `.keys()` so that's why you get the AttributeError.  You can, however, iterate over the dictionaries within this object and ask, whether any of those (inner) dictionaries has given key.  The built-in function `any()` does that for you, but it is similar to:

```
for inner_dictionary in user.values():
    if uname in inner_dictionary.keys():
        print('Hello!')
        break
```